# split list of string lines and add words to a new list

Tags: java, list, algorithm, split, java-stream

I don't really feel comfortable with the following code, but I don't know how to implement it in a more efficient way.

```
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String line : newList) {
        String[] lineArray = line.split(" ");
        for (String l : lineArray) {
            words.add(l);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define “efficient”. If you mean “performance”, it’s as fast as it can be unless you want to introduce multiple threads. Or do you mean “minimum code” or “elegant code”?

Comment: maybe something with the same performance but more "elegant"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant way would be as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        List<String> newList = List.of("Amitabh Bachchan", "James Bond", "Kishore Kumar", "Arvind Kumar Avinash");
        List<String> words = newList.stream().flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Amitabh, Bachchan, James, Bond, Kishore, Kumar, Arvind, Kumar, Avinash]
```